# neo4j : jQuery not returning expected result on apoc.load.html

Tags: jquery, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Given the html file below:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2 id='KPILIST'> Blah Blah 1</h2>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Col 1 Header</th><th>Col 2 Header</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 1.1 Value</td><td>Line 2.1 Header</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 2.1 Value</td><td>Line 2.2 Value</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Col 1 Header T2</th><th>Col 2 Header T2</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 1.1 Value T2</td><td>Line 2.1 Header T2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 2.1 Value T2</td><td>Line 2.2 Value T2</td></tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the below code to return the first bloc of 3 lines from the first table above

```
// Blah Blah
CALL apoc.load.html("file:///XXX.html",{line: "#KPILIST ~ div:eq(0) div > table tr"}) yield value as lineList
unwind (lineList.line) as L
RETURN L
```

But unfortunately nothing is returned
Even a simple query like `table:eq(0)` doesn't work as it returns both tables and not only the first one

Answer (score 0):

apoc.call.load is based on jsoup and not jQuery

The above query should be :

```
"h2#KPILIST + div tr"
```

Please find below the link to the jsoup selectors syntax:

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax